# Is @FXML needed for every declaration?

Tags: javafx, fxml, fxmlloader

Is @FXML needed for every declaration or just for the first?

In other words, should I use

```
@FXML
public Label timerLabel = new Label();
@FXML
public TextField mainTextField, projectTextField ;
@FXML
public Button goButton, deleteAllButton ;
@FXML
public ComboBox<String> projectComboBox ;
@FXML
public TableView<Entry> mainTable ;
@FXML
public TableColumn<Entry, String> titleColumn, timeColumn, dateColumn ;
@FXML
public TableColumn<Entry, Boolean> checkColumn, buttonColumn ;
@FXML
public checkBox checkAllCheckBox ;
```

Or

```
@FXML
public Label timerLabel = new Label();
public TextField mainTextField, projectTextField ;
public Button goButton, deleteAllButton ;
public ComboBox<String> projectComboBox ;
public TableView<Entry> mainTable ;
public TableColumn<Entry, String> titleColumn, timeColumn, dateColumn ;
public TableColumn<Entry, Boolean> checkColumn, buttonColumn ;
public checkBox checkAllCheckBox ;
```

Thank you!

Comment: Tryout both of them ;)

Comment: I can't see any differences :|

Comment: I never seen the second solution. I think it's not possible. just try

Comment: @Romeo Have you tried using them? ;)

Comment: @Romeo Just to point out, your statement `public Label timerLabel = new Label();` annotated by `@FXML` is incorrect. The references annotated with `@FXML` are initialized at the time of fxml load and should not be initialized externally.

Comment: I know it's a stupid question... I have already used them. I was just wondering if there are any syntactic differences

Comment: Should I initialize timerLabel in initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources)?

Comment: What do you mean by "initialize timerLabel"?  You should never write `timerLabel = new TimerLabel()` if the timerLabel reference definition was annotated with `@FXML`.

Comment: You don't actually need any `@FXML` annotations if your fields are `public`. Of course, you should never make these fields `public` anyway; you should make them `private`, in which case all the `@FXML` annotations are required. But with the code as it is, omitting the annotations will make no difference.

Comment: I think it is time to FXMLLoader to log error or warn if the @FXML annotated field is already instantiated while loading. Or use instantiated one as in setController().

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The `@FXML` annotation enables an `FXMLLoader` to inject values defined in an FXML file into references in the controller class. In other words, if you annotate your `timerLabel` with `@FXML`, then it will be initialized by the `FXMLLoader` when the `load()` method is called by an element in the FXML file with `fx:id="timerLabel"`. As others have pointed out in the comments, this means you should never write code like

```
@FXML
private Label timerLabel = new Label();
```

Here `timerLabel` will first be initialized to the `new Label();` you create in the code, and will then almost immediately be re-initialized to the value defined in the FXML file. This is at best redundant, and at worst misleading. If you don't correctly match the variable names to the `fx:id`, your variable will be referring to the wrong `Label` and the error will be very difficult to track down.

To get to your actual question:

When the `FXMLLoader` loads the FXML file, it will attempt to inject any elements that have an `fx:id` attribute into the controller. It will look for

1. Any `public` field with a variable name matching the `fx:id` attribute, *or*
2. Any field (`public` or not) with a variable name matching the `fx:id` attribute that is annotated with `@FXML`.

So in your example, since all your fields are `public`, you can omit all the `@FXML` annotations (even the first) and it will still work.

However, if you follow good practice and make your fields `private`, then each declaration must be annotated `@FXML` for the injection to work.

So

```
@FXML
private Label timerLabel;
@FXML
private TextField mainTextField;
```

etc will work, but

```
@FXML
private Label timerLabel;
private TextField mainTextField;
```

will not.

Comment: Is injection required? Is there a way to just ask the loader for the control I'm interested in (by fx:id)?

Comment: Not sure I understand that question. Isn't that exactly what injection does?

Answer (score 8):

for each

```
fx:id="somename"
```

you need a

```
@FXML
public SomeClass somename;
```

I prefer writing it in one line, because it's easier to read when there are many

```
@FXML public SomeClass somename;
```

without initializing

```
@FXML
public Label timerLabel = new Label(); // this is wrong
```

Comment: won't `timerLabel = new Label();` be overridden by an `FXMLLoader `?

Comment: This answer is misleading, since `@FXML` isn't needed when the field is public. So `public SomeClass somename;` without `@FXML` does also work, but you need it when `somename` isn't `public` for example `@FXML private SomeClass somename;`.

Answer (score 0):

```
@FXML
private TextField idTextField;

@FXML
private TextField passwordTextField;
```

OR

```
@FXML
private TextField idTextField, passwordTextField;
```