# JavaFX - can't add data to database

Tags: sql, database, javafx

I'm trying to make gui,who will add employees to database. I'm writing this post,because i've got an error.

```
    Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8413)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:394)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$353(GlassViewEventHandler.java:432)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:431)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
    ... 48 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at addEmployee.addEmployeeController.add(addEmployeeController.java:38)
    ... 58 more

Process finished with exit code 0
```

addEmployee.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.112" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="addEmployee.addEmployeeController">
   <children>
      <TextField fx:id="nameTF" layoutX="205.0" layoutY="57.0" promptText="name" />
      <TextField fx:id="surnameTF" layoutX="205.0" layoutY="103.0" promptText="surname" />
      <TextField fx:id="ageTF" layoutX="205.0" layoutY="143.0" promptText="age" />
      <Button fx:id="addBTN" layoutX="205.0" layoutY="188.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#add" text="Add" />
      <Button fx:id="cancelBTN" layoutX="300.0" layoutY="188.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#cancel" text="Cancel" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

addEmployeeController

```
package addEmployee;

import Database.DatabaseHandler;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.*;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;



public class addEmployeeController implements Initializable{

    DatabaseHandler databaseHandler;

    @FXML
    private TextField name;
    @FXML
    private TextField surname;
    @FXML
    private TextField age;
    @FXML
    private Button add;
    @FXML
    private Button cancel;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        databaseHandler = new DatabaseHandler();

    }
    @FXML
    private void add(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        String employeeName = name.getText();
        String employeeSurname = surname.getText();
        String employeeAge = age.getText();

        if (employeeName.isEmpty() || employeeSurname.isEmpty() || employeeAge.isEmpty()){
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
            alert.setHeaderText(null);
            alert.setContentText("Please enter in all fields");
            alert.showAndWait();
            return;
        }

        String qu = "INSERT INTO Employees VALUES ("
                +"'"+employeeName+",'"
                +"'"+employeeSurname+",'"
                +""+employeeAge+""
                +")";

        System.out.println(qu);
        if (databaseHandler.execAction(qu)) {
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
            alert.setHeaderText(null);
            alert.setContentText("Succes");
            alert.showAndWait();

        }else//error
        {
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
            alert.setHeaderText(null);
            alert.setContentText("Failed");
            alert.showAndWait();
        }
    }


    public void cancel(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    }
}
```

Main

```
package addEmployee;

import Database.DatabaseHandler;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/addEmployee/addEmployee.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
        primaryStage.show();


    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

DatabaseHandler

```
package Database;

import java.sql.*;

public class DatabaseHandler {

    public static final String Driver = "org.sqlite.JDBC";
    private static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:sqlite:TEST.db";

    private static Connection connection = null;
    private static Statement statement = null;


    public DatabaseHandler() {

        try {
            Class.forName(DatabaseHandler.Driver);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("No driver JDBC");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL);
            statement = connection.createStatement();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Problem with opening the connection");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        createTables();
    }

    public boolean createTables() {
        String createEmployees = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Employees (Employee_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name varchar(255), surname varchar(255), age int)";

        try {
            statement.execute(createEmployees);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Problem with creating a table");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public boolean insertEmployees(String name, String surname, int age) {
        try {
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("insert into Employees values (NULL,?,?,?);");
            preparedStatement.setString(1,name);
            preparedStatement.setString(2,surname);
            preparedStatement.setInt(3,age);
            preparedStatement.execute();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Error with insert an employee to the table");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public ResultSet execQuery(String query){
        ResultSet resultSet;
        try {
            statement = connection.createStatement();
            resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);
        }catch (SQLException e){
            System.out.println("Error in exec query\n"+e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }finally {
        }
        return resultSet;
    }

    public boolean execAction(String qu){
        try {
            statement = connection.createStatement();
            statement.execute(qu);
            return true;
        }catch (SQLException e){
            System.out.println("excecption at exec action\n"+e.getMessage());
            return false;
        }finally {

        }
    }

    public void closeConnection() {
        try {
            connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println("Error with shutdown");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

My program runs normal,but when i click on Add button,i've receives this error. How i can repair it ?  Can you guys link me some good tutorial to make properly gui ?

Comment: Your `fx:id`s don't match the field names in the controller.

Comment: Have you tried running it in an debugger and setting a break point on the line that throws the error?

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30210170/is-fxml-needed-for-every-declaration/30213067#30213067 is also helpful. @Kerry I'm not sure a debugger here would reveal anything that isn't already immediately obvious from the stack trace: `name` is null.

Comment: @James_D: `give a man a fish and you feed him for a day; teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime`

Comment: @Kerry At risk of stretching the metaphor too far, you need to teach him what a fish is first. Learning to read and understand a stack trace is a far more fundamental (and important, imho) skill than using a debugger. And a debugger here will not tell you why the field is null, because its initialized via injection by the framework; so it would really just be a distraction.