# Javafx table view in scenebuilder not inserting user input

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

I'am currently working on a project where I'am trying to implement a `TableView` that takes in user input (Name, Rating, Restaurant Name). Below I have provided my code that is already in my Controller class. The problem that I'm having is that whenever I type anything in the textfields and click the "submit" button it does absolutely nothing. What could possibly be the problem?

Here is the beginning and end of my code, I did not include the rest because the Login method is the only one giving me problems when I try to initialize.

```
public class MainController{


@FXML
private Label lblStatus;
@FXML
private TextField txtUsername;
@FXML
private TextField txtPassword;



/*This method allows user login and when login is successful then user is taken to the main screen.*/     


public void Login (ActionEvent event) throws Exception {
    if (txtUsername.getText().equals("user") && txtPassword.getText().equals("pass")) {
        lblStatus.setText("Login Success");
        Stage primaryStage = new Stage();
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/application/RestScene.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setTitle("Restaurant Advisor");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    else
    {
        lblStatus.setText("Login Failed");
    }
}



public TableView<Table> tableview;
public TableColumn<Table, String> colName;
public TableColumn<Table, Integer> colRating;
public TableColumn<Table, String>colRestaurants;
public TextField txtFieldName;
public TextField txtFieldRating;
public TextField txtFieldRestaurant;

public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    colName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("TableName"));
    colRating.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("TableRating"));
    colRestaurants.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("TableRestaurants"));
    tableview.setItems(observableList);
}

ObservableList<Table> observableList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(new Table ("Test", 1, "makiyaki"));


public void buttonSubmit(ActionEvent event) {

    Table table = new Table (txtFieldName.getText(), Integer.parseInt(txtFieldRating.getText()), txtFieldRestaurant.getText());
    tableview.getItems().add(table);
}
```

Here is the FXML code for the specific tableview

```xml
    <AnchorPane layoutX="596.0" layoutY="338.0" prefHeight="284.0" prefWidth="461.0">
         <children>
            <TableView fx:id="tableview" layoutX="-3.0" layoutY="-1.0" prefHeight="243.0" prefWidth="315.0">
              <columns>
                <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Name" />
                <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Rating" />
                  <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Restaurant" />
              </columns>
            </TableView>
            <TextField fx:id="txtFieldName" layoutX="39.0" layoutY="253.0" prefHeight="12.0" prefWidth="83.0" promptText="Name" />
            <TextField fx:id="txtFieldRating" layoutX="173.0" layoutY="249.0" prefHeight="12.0" prefWidth="83.0" promptText="Rating" />
            <TextField fx:id="txtFieldRestaurant" layoutX="317.0" layoutY="239.0" prefHeight="12.0" prefWidth="83.0" promptText="Restaurant" />
            <Button layoutX="341.0" layoutY="58.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#buttonSubmit" text="Submit" />
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: I assume you pass the controller to the `FXMLLoader` using `setController` before calling `load`? Furthermore does the initial element appear? If not, are there selectable, empty rows in the table? (Post the `Table` class in this case).

Comment: Can you debug and see if the method gets called or not?

Comment: Did you try add that item on your observable list ?

Comment: replace you codes with the full fxml and full controller

Answer (score 1):

- You haven't inserted `fx:id` into your table columns in the fxml. Its gonna cause a NullPointerException in your `initalize()` as soon its run, from what you said that nothing happens when you click on submit, it means that the `initialize()` hasn't been called by the application in the first place.
- Your `initialize()` needs to be a no-arg method for it to get called. [See here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/Initializable.html) or else if you want to do it your way i.e `initialize(URL, ResourceBundle)` make your controller implement the aforementioned `Initializable` interface
- go through [this question once your're done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30210170/is-fxml-needed-for-every-declaration)

Comment: Since my controller class includes other code that does not need to be initialized, I'm not able to do this.  It gives me errors.

Comment: I don't understand. Just replace `public class MainController` with `public class MainController implements Initializable` and import the `Initializable` interface.

Comment: When I do that i get errors, whenever I implements Initializable. i've posted my updated code above without the initializable interface because it gives me errors with it implemented

Comment: Then just remove the parameters in the `initialize()`

Answer (score -1):

You're missing @FXML tag on your `buttonSubmit` method

Comment: I added @FXML but it didn't change anything

Comment: This shouldn't matter. `public` members are accessible to `FXMLLoader` by default. Only non-public members need to be annotated.

Comment: Does it matter at all that I placed the tableview in an anchorpane within the main anchorpane?

Comment: @BlytheS. No this does not matter. In fact you do not need to create a scene using fxml; you could also e.g. create a `ArrayList` of `String`s. Injection/handlers should work regardless of the object structure created based on the fxml.