# JavaFX ImageView not updating

Tags: image, file, javafx, imageview, file-browser

So I'm trying to load and save Images into an imageView where the location of the image is chosen through a file browser. I've been working on this for several days now and I'm gonna have a stroke if I can't get it fixed. I've tried everything I can think of. Thank you in advance for helping.

**UPDATED**:

Here is my main class:

```
public class Main extends Application {
    private Stage primaryStage;
    private BorderPane rootLayout;
    public Main(){}
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
      this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
      this.primaryStage.setTitle("Help Please");
      initRootLayout();
      showScreen();
    }
    public void initRootLayout(){
        try{
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("view/RootLayout.fxml"));
            rootLayout = (BorderPane) loader.load();
            Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            RootLayout controller = loader.getController();
            controller.setMain(this);
            primaryStage.show();
        }catch(Exception e ){e.printStackTrace();}
    }
    public void showScreen(){
        try{FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("view/sample.fxml"));
        BorderPane sample = (BorderPane)loader.load();
        rootLayout.setCenter(sample);
        Controller controller = loader.getController();
        controller.setMain(this);
        }catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
    }
    public Stage getPrimaryStage(){return primaryStage;}
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Here is the rootLayout:

```
public class RootLayout {
    private Main main;
    private Controller controller = new Controller();
    public void setMain(Main main){this.main = main;}
    @FXML
    private void handleOpen(){
        FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
        FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extensionFilter = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter(
                "PNG files (*.png)","*png");
        fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().add(extensionFilter);
        File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(main.getPrimaryStage());
        if(file!= null){
            controller.updateImage(file.toURI().toString());
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the controller:

```
public class Controller implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView();
    String imageURL;
    Main main = new Main();
    public void setMain(Main main){
        this.main = main;
    }
    public void updateImage(String url){
        if(url.length()>=1){
            Image image = new Image(url);
            imageView.setImage(image);
            System.out.println(url);
        }
        else{
            System.out.println(url);
            System.out.println("image invalid");
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    }
}
```

Comment: You are using the @FXML tag for the imageView meaning that you do not have to create a new ImageView. Here's just a tip, the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30210170/is-fxml-needed-for-every-declaration) explains well why this is the case.

Comment: How did you get your fxml to load? If the first code snippet is indeed from your controller, the fact that you're passing `null` to the `updateImage` method should result in a `NullPointerException` at `if(url.length()<=1){` perventing you from properly loading the scene.

Comment: Could you please create a [mre] that demonstrates the problem, then add it to your question via an [edit]? The example should be minimal, but _complete_, which means we should be able to copy the code to our machines and execute it with little to no modifications.

Comment: @Slaw I have now updated it to be a minimal reproducible example now please help me if you can. thanks

Comment: @Robert Thank you for your response. I have since removed the unnecessary creation of a new ImageView. It did not change the problem. If you have any more help that would be great.

Comment: @Fabian Thank you for your comment. When I recreated the problem in another file I got the errors you were talking about and have since fixed them. I would still greatly appreciate further help you can offer.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. **Never** assign a field whose value is to be injected by an `FXMLLoader` (e.g. `@FXML` fields). Doing so is a waste of resources at best and introduces subtle bugs at worst. For instance, if you were to leave the `imageView` field uninitialized you'd be getting a `NullPointerException` which would indicate a problem with your setup. Since you *do* initialize the field, however, you don't get any errors and there's a false impression of the code working.
2. In your `RootLayout` controller class, you have:

   > ```
   > private Controller controller = new Controller();
   > ```

   That instance of `Controller` you just created is not linked to any FXML file. And since you initialize the `imageView` field (see first point) you end up updating an `ImageView` which is not being displayed anywhere; this is where not initializing said field would have given a nice indication of there being a problem. The solution is to pass the `Controller` instance created by the `FXMLLoader` to the `RootLayout` instance created by the other `FXMLLoader`.

   Also, in the same class you have:

   > ```
   > Main main = new Main();
   > ```

   Which is also unnecessary since the created instance of `Main` is both not the correct instance and is replaced by the call to `#setMain(Main)` almost immediately.

---

Assuming your FXML files (which you did not provide) are correct, the Java classes should look more like:

**Main.java**

```java
public class Main extends Application {

  private Stage primaryStage;
  private BorderPane rootLayout;
  private RootLayout rootLayoutController;

  public Main() {}

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
    this.primaryStage.setTitle("Help Please");
    initRootLayout();
    showScreen();
  }

  public void initRootLayout() {
    try {
      FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
      loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("view/RootLayout.fxml"));
      rootLayout = (BorderPane) loader.load();
      Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
      primaryStage.setScene(scene);

      // store RootLayout instance in field so #showScreen()
      // can reference it
      rootLayoutController = loader.getController();
      rootLayoutController.setMain(this);

      primaryStage.show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public void showScreen() {
    try {
      FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
      loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("view/sample.fxml"));
      BorderPane sample = (BorderPane) loader.load();
      rootLayout.setCenter(sample);
      Controller controller = loader.getController();
      controller.setMain(this);

      // set Controller instance on RootLayout instance
      rootLayoutController.setController(controller);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public Stage getPrimaryStage() {
    return primaryStage;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }
}
```

**RootLayout.java**

```java
public class RootLayout {

  private Main main;
  private Controller controller;

  public void setMain(Main main) {
    this.main = main;
  }

  public void setController(Controller controller) {
    this.controller = controller;
  }

  @FXML
  private void handleOpen() {
    FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
    // Note extensions should be prefixed with "*."
    FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extensionFilter =
        new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("PNG files (*.png)", "*.png");
    fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().add(extensionFilter);
    File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(main.getPrimaryStage());
    if (file != null) {
      controller.updateImage(file.toURI().toString());
    }
  }
}
```

**Controller.java**

```java
public class Controller implements Initializable {

  @FXML ImageView imageView; // leave uninitialized, will be injected
  String imageURL;
  Main main;

  public void setMain(Main main) {
    this.main = main;
  }

  public void updateImage(String url) {
    if (url.length() >= 1) {
      Image image = new Image(url);
      imageView.setImage(image);
      System.out.println(url);
    } else {
      System.out.println(url);
      System.out.println("image invalid");
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {}
}
```

***Note:** Did not test new code.*

Comment: Thank you for your response. I changed the things you were telling me to, but now what I get is a NullPointerException pointing to the      `controller.updateImage(file.toURI().toString());` in the handleOpen() in the RootLayoutController. I know you mentioned that that would be happening if i didnt initialize the imageview but how would I point it to the right place so that I dont have to get the NullPointer

Comment: I just created some mock FXML files based on the given code; I cannot reproduce the `NullPointerException` and the `ImageView` is updated correctly. Are you sure you included the `rootLayoutController.setController(controller);` code? And your FXML file has an `fx:id="imageView"` attribute for the `ImageView` element, correct?