# JavaFX - How to switch to another tab with mouse click event

Tags: javafx, tabs

I added a tabpane to my program with 2 tabs on it.

A table view is on the 1st tab

I want to click on a row of the table to switch to 2nd tab and show something there, but it fails.

Here is my simplified controller class:

```
@FXML
private TabPane myTabpane;

@FXML
private Tab tab1;

@FXML
private Tab tab2;

@FXML
private void handleClickTable(MouseEvent event) {
    if (event.getClickCount() == 2) {
        MyObject selectedObject = myTableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        doSomething(selectedObject);
    }
}

@FXML
void initialize(){

    myTabpane = new TabPane();

    tab1 = new Tab();

    tab2 = new Tab();
}


public void doSomething(MyObject myObject) {
    System.out.println("Mouse clicked! Let's do something with "+ myObject.getName());
    myTabpane.getSelectionModel().select(tab2);
}
```

I could get the println statement when I click on the table, but it do not switch to tab2. Can anybody point out what's wrong with my code? Thanks!

Comment: Check out Slaw's answer on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59253649/javafx-imageview-not-updating?noredirect=1#comment104784791_59253649) and more specifically the first section of his answer. In short, remove the three lines of code in your initialize method.

Comment: Thanks. It finally works. But what confuses me is that I didn't add those codes in my first attempt. It didn't work and throw an no pointer exception. That's why I added them. It now works just by deleting those 3 lines.

Comment: Im glad it works. Whatever issue you had before must have been caused by something else which you then changed afterwards as well :)